# WebStorm 8 EAP do not start after update

Tags: macos, webstorm

I have update WebStorm 8 EAP today and the program is totally inactive after that. Do not start, do not show splash screen

Comment: Visit this [thread](http://goo.gl/x5yUuh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reinstalling from scratch:

1. Delete WebStorm from /Applications/
2. Remove all the configs and related settings by running the following commands:

   ```
   rm -rf "$HOME/Library/Preferences/WebStorm8"
   rm -rf "$HOME/Library/Caches/WebStorm8"
   rm -rf "$HOME/Library/Application Support/WebStorm8"
   rm -rf "$HOME/Library/Logs/WebStorm8"
   ```

Comment: Hi, yes It helped. For moment.
I have delete the folders, install WebStorm 8 EAP, import previous setup from WebStorm 7, launch, open few previous projects - everything works fine. Install Node.js source code visa settings dialog.

Comment: And since than I am unable to launch the program again.

Comment: not sure I've got what you mean... Is everything working fine now? what's wrong with Node.js sources (if anything is wrong)?

Comment: I am unable to start program again - it do not respond at all. And I was describing what I did from the point of deleting the folders to to point unable to launch the app.

Comment: do you mean that it failes to start after configuring Node sources? it's strange. I'd suggest creating a support ticket

Comment: Well, I do not know if that is related but it was the last thing I did. Yes, the ticket might be good idea.

Comment: I think the issue is related with import of previous version settings. It stop responding after the new install with previous setting import and closing the application. Than I install it without settings import and works fine now.

Comment: it's fine. But I still suggest creating a ticket. BTW, how do you import them? Via File/Import settings, or?